# How to make a monocrystalline silicon seed

Tags: semiconductor-physics, experimental-technique

I do understand that you can grow monocrystalline silicon from an initial seed but I'm lost in a chicken versus egg situation where I don't understand how you can get the seed if the only way to make monocrystalline silicon is by using a seed.

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of a few materials (e.g. silica) everything forms crystals in the solid phase, but the crystals can be very small and randomly arranged. We call such material [polycrystalline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallite). The individual crystallites can be very small, but luckily we only need a very small crystal as a seed.

I don't know exactly how the seeds for growing silicon boules are obtained, but if you allow silicon to solidify from the melt slowly, or deposit it slowly using CVD, it will grow crystallites big enough to be used as a seed.

Having said this, my guess is that in practice the seeds are simply cut from a previous boule so they don't need to be grown.

Comment: You mean silicon, not silicone.

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan I wasn't aware of the CVD process, certainly helpful